# Cakemail embedded images view as attachments in gmail

Tags: php, email, cakephp, email-attachments

I'm working with cakephp 2.x and I try to send email with embedded images. When I send to email to my website email and open it with outlook images shows correctly, but send to gmail and open it with web browser (chrome) images show as attachments. My code samples shows below, is there any mistake here or need configurations cakemail to prevent this problem??? thank you.

in my `view/Emails/html` (part of code)

```
<tr>
   <td align="center" valign="top">
      <a href="<?php echo FULL_BASE_URL.'/call_to_actions/view/'.$fundid;?>" title="zzzz" target="_blank">
         <img style="display:block;margin:0;border:0;padding:0;" src="image_09.jpg" alt="zzzzz" width="184" height="45" border="0" />
      </a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

in my model

```
public function sendEmails($to, $from, $sender, $senderN, $subject, $massage, $template='default') {
    $Email = new CakeEmail('smtp'); 
    $Email  ->  template($template,'default')
            ->  emailFormat('html')
            ->  helpers(array('Html'))
            ->  to($to)
            ->  from($from)
            ->  sender($sender,$senderN)
            ->  subject($subject)
            ->  attachments(array('../webroot/img/email/image_05.jpg', '../webroot/img/email/image_09.jpg'))
            ->  viewVars($massage)  
            ->  send();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you attach/embed the images inline as shown in the manual? **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#sending-attachments**

Comment: finally it work with nested array with custom Content ID (4th one). thank you :)